Water pump running for 30 minutes before stopping
Our water tank /well is losing water quite fast, much faster than usual. We switched off the water pump for 15 hrs to check if the tank was leaking but the level never moved. After turning the pump back on the pump ran for 30 minutes before switching off. Now 30 minutes is way too long just to refill 3 toilets, what could be the issue?
Its an on-demand pump so nothing works when it is switched off, you can only flush a toilet once. If its a pipe leak then it would be running almost constantly and it isn't
Grundfos MQ-3-45 (1HP) On Demand Pump (115V)
Any insight appreciated.

Pump wearing out/leaking, or water level in the well too low/not filling up fast enough.  More information of your setup and include any check valves/back flow preventers.

What "tank?" - you claim to have an on-demand pump - those generally don't go with a tank. Please [edit] to clarify.
